# How to put colon inbetween elements of a big number using python

Tags: python-2.7

My question is my title  . I want to put colon to number 2034820. It should look like 2:03:48:20
Basically this is my time data in HHMMSSMS format i.e hour minute second and millisecond.I want to plot other data with respect to this time format. How can I plot my data in y-axis and time of given format in x-axis.

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt('inputfile.dat') fig=plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(111) sat1=ax1.plot(data[:,1],'b',linewidth=1,label='SVID-127') 
sat2 = ax1.plot(data[:,2],'m-',linewidth=1,label='SVID-128')
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Did you tried DateTime.datetime class method

Comment: No. When I plotted  I could see my plot is over the length of other data.

Comment: Can you share your code here.

Comment: before coming to plotting i want to convert time to UTC format . But data is odd number so if I convert I get 20:34:82:00 which is not proper

Comment: how to share code. I f i share code it is coming in one line. Anyway I will try

Comment: data = numpy.genfromtxt('inputfile.dat')
fig=plt.figure() #sorry I am unable to put my code like others

Comment: ax1=plt.subplot(111)
sat1=ax1.plot(data[:,1],'b',linewidth=1,label='SVID-127')
sat2=ax1.plot(data[:,2],'m-',linewidth=1,label='SVID-128')

Comment: my time is 20347.00,20347.20,20347.40... i want like 02:03:47:00 etc and finally want to like plot(t,data[]:,2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can parse the time with [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and then re-`format` it:

```
from datetime import datetime

tme = datetime.strptime('{:08d}'.format(2034820), '%H%M%S%f').time()
strg = '{0:%H:%M:%S:%f}'.format(tme)
print(strg[:-4]) # cut the trailing '0000'
# 02:03:48:20
```

this assumes your input is an integer (which will be converted to a zero-padded string of length 8 with `'{:08d}'.format(2034820)`; if the data comes as string you need to convert it to an int first: `'{:08d}'.format(int('2034820'))`).

---

from your comments: you seem to be getting the number of seconds that have passed since midnight. for those you could to this:

```
from datetime import time

def convert(timefloat):
    hours, rest = divmod(timefloat, 3600)
    mins, rest = divmod(rest, 60)
    secs, rest = divmod(rest, 1)
    microsecs = int(10**6 * rest)
    tme = time(int(hours), int(mins), int(secs), microsecs)
    return '{0:%H:%M:%S:%f}'.format(tme)[:-4]
```

which gives for your test-data:

```
for d in data:
    print(convert(d))

#23:59:59:58
#23:59:59:80
#23:59:59:99
#00:00:00:20
#00:00:00:40
#00:00:00:60
```

Comment: thanks for responding I want 02:03:48:20 . it is hhmmssms where ms is milliseconds. My data is odd number. I am reading from a file and I have 40000 lines

Comment: I am new here and do not know how to give upvote. tell me the step definitely i will do

Comment: if u do not mind I am stuck once again. See my data is massive.It is 24 hours data. so when it completes 24 hours it comebacks to 0 and proceed to 20 40 60 milliseconds and gains time. Here my loop using your previous code is failing .how to overcome this now?

Comment: this is not the format from your question. these are seconds (1 day = 86,400 s)...

Comment: Thank-you so much .It really awesome and helpful and sorry if it had created any ambiguity for you. Thanks once again

Comment: sorry for so many questions . just wanted to know how to store the data in one more file in column wise . I have tried for d in data[:,0]:
         f.write(convert(d))   . But it is storing in one line horizontally . I want vertically one after another

Comment: sorry, i do not understand... please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and open a new question.

Comment: Hi , Say i have data=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,10 and time is 05:39:09:20
05:39:09:40
05:39:09:59
05:39:09:79
05:39:10:00
05:39:10:20
05:39:10:40
05:39:10:59
05:39:10:79. How can I plot data over this time format using matplotlib.